# Extract words based on regex

Tags: python, regex, pandas

I am trying to extract whatever appears after the word SUITE, suite, ste, Ste. or the character # in a pandas dataframe column. The examples are like below

```
4230 Harding Pike Ste 435
4230 Harding Pike Suite 435
4230 Harding Pike SUITE A
4230 Harding Pike Ste. 101
4230 Harding Pike SUITE B-200
4230 Harding Pike #900
4230 Harding Pike STE 503
4230 Harding Pike SUITE 300
4230 Harding Pike Ste 700
4230 Harding Pike SUITE #2
```

Result:

```
SuiteNos

435
435  
A
101
B-200
900
503
300
700
2
```

I tried with the below regexes but it does not work as expected -

```
 df_merged['address'].str.extract(r'\**\**suite.*\**\**')
 df_merged['address'] = re.findall('@([suite]+)', df_merged['address'])
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using a case insensitive match, you could use a capture group with an alternation:

```
(?i)(?:#|Suite|ste\.?)\s*([^\s#].*)
```

The pattern matches:

- `(?:` Non capture group

  - `Suite` Match literally
  - `|` Or
  - `ste\.?` Match ste with an optional dot
  - `|` Or
  - `#` Match literally
- `)` close non capture group
- `\s*` Match optional whitspace chars
- `([^\s#].*)` Capture group 1, start with matching a non whitespace char without # and the rest of the line

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/jHW0cJ/1)

```
import pandas as pd

strings = [
    "4230 Harding Pike Ste 435",
    "4230 Harding Pike Suite 435",
    "4230 Harding Pike SUITE A",
    "4230 Harding Pike Ste. 101",
    "4230 Harding Pike SUITE B-200",
    "4230 Harding Pike #900",
    "4230 Harding Pike STE 503",
    "4230 Harding Pike SUITE 300",
    "4230 Harding Pike Ste 700",
    "4230 Harding Pike SUITE #2"
]

pattern = r"(?i)(?:#|Suite|ste\.?)\s*([^\s#].*)"
df_merged = pd.DataFrame(strings, columns = ['address'])
df_merged['SuiteNos'] = df_merged['address'].str.extract(pattern)

print(df_merged["SuiteNos"])
```

Output

```
0      435
1      435
2        A
3      101
4    B-200
5      900
6      503
7      300
8      700
9        2
```

Comment: The examples suggest that `#` can only be followed by digits. If so, you would need a small mod. btw, this is the 1 millionth example of ambiguities created by stating a question in terms of examples only.

Answer (score 3):

With your shown samples, please try following regex.

```
(?:(?:[Ss](?:[uU][iI])?[tT][eE]\.?\s+)#?|#)(\S+)
```

In ***Pandas*** run following code:

```
df['value'].str.extract(r'(?:(?:[Ss](?:[uU][iI])?[tT][eE]\.?\s+)#?|#)(\S+)')
```

Output from above code in Pandas with samples provided by OP will be as follows:

```
0      435
1      435
2        A
3      101
4    B-200
5      NaN
6      503
7      300
8      700
9        2
Name: value, dtype: object
```

[Online demo for above regex](https://regex101.com/r/osGa5V/1)

***Explanation:*** Adding detailed explanation for above.

```
(?:                   ##Starting a non-capturing group here.
  (?:                 ##Starting another non-capturing group here.
     [Ss]             ##Matching small OR capital S here.
     (?:[uU][iI])?    ##In a non-capturing group matching u/U i/I and keep this optional.
     [tT][eE]\.?\s+   ##Matching t or T followed by e or E here followed by optional dot and 1 or more spaces here.
  )                   ##Closing 2nd non-capturing group here.
  #?|#                ##Matching # keeping it optional OR matching it no optional.
)                     ##Closing 1st non-capturing group here.
(\S+)                 ##Creating 1st capturing group which contains all non-spaces in it.
```

Thanks to @The fourth bird for helping in tweak to make only 1 capturing group to catch all matched things.